# Error when i am debuggin Fastapi + mongdb

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, uvicorn

I have 2 versions in this code to explain my problem.
When i execute **uvicorn main:app --reload** both versions work perfectly. My problem appear when i am debugging.

When i use the version 1 and comment the version 2 i can debug without problems but when i use the version 2 and comment the version 1 i get this error:

**created_user = await users_collection.insert_one(form_dict)**

**RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-7' coro=<RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi() running at C:\Users\c\PycharmProjects\fastapi_test_fallo_loop\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py:394> cb=[set.discard()]> got Future <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.._call_check_cancel() at C:\Users\c\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py:360]> attached to a different loop**

Why does this error appear?

Should I always work with version 1?

```
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient

# version 1
'''
class DataBase:
   client: AsyncIOMotorClient = None
   usersDB = None

db = DataBase()

async def connect_to_mongo():
   db.client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://mongo:mongo@19*****:27017/admin?retryWrites=false")
   db.usersDB = db.client.app

async def close_mongo_connection():
   db.client.close()

# end version 1
'''
# version 2
DB_CLIENT = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://mongo:mongo@19*****:27017/admin?retryWrites=false")
db = DB_CLIENT['app']
# end version 2
```

Here i have my main.py with a method to register an user and explain my problem

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, HTTPException
# from app.mongodb import connect_to_mongo, close_mongo_connection  # version 1
from app.mongodb import db  # version 2, version 1
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()


# app.add_event_handler("startup", connect_to_mongo)  # version 1
# app.add_event_handler("shutdown", close_mongo_connection)  # version 1


@app.post("/register")
async def register(username: str = Form(..., max_length=50)):
   form_dict = {'username': username}
   # users_collection = db.usersDB.get_collection('users')  # version 1
   users_collection = db.get_collection('users')  # version 2
   created_user = await users_collection.insert_one(form_dict)
   if created_user:
      return JSONResponse(status_code=200,
                        content='user is created correctly')
   else:
      raise HTTPException(status_code=400,
                        detail='user is not created correctly')


   if __name__ == "__main__":
     import uvicorn
     uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Comment: When you are using async , you should consider that objects that you create that have a method must use a same async loop. in version 2 you create motor client in second loop and you can't use that in first loop. for this problem you should use same loop.
like your first version. this problem happens because of uvicorn. if you use gunicorn with uvicorn workers this never be happened.